# How can i fetch Database column names and how can i manage it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Problem:
SQL Server table is vertical grid with options, i want the same thing to be done in asp.net with c#,
i want to connect the system with the table, it will fetch table column names with check boxes on front, and when we would check or uncheck, the value would be stored in sql server table, as we edit using SQL Server management studio, i want the same component vertically integrated into my web application. Please let me know, can we use grid vertically or there is some control for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to iterate through the properties of the table you want.  Display this information in a format that you like, and then write various small queries to edit whatever you want to be editable.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DatabaseSpy_CS.aspx

http://www.sqlrecipes.com/sql_questions_answers/how_get_table_structure_via_sql-92

http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=SQL+Table+Structure+c%23